# I am encountering a Branching Issue with ruby

Tags: ruby, syntax-error, branch

question, I am trying to run this in my command line. I am using the latest ruby, on Windows... Is it my computer?
 syntax error, unexpected t identifier is the message that pops up.

```
puts "Hello, what\'s your name?"
name = gets.chomp puts "Hello, " + name + "."

if name == 'Chris' puts "What a lovely name!"
if name == 'Joey' puts "Wow! That\'s an even better name than Chris"
gets
```

where am i screwing up at?

Comment: You forgot an `end` keyword for your `if` statements.

Answer (score 1):

Looks small preference mistake:

```
puts "Hello, what\'s your name?"
name = gets.chomp
puts "Hello, " + name + "."

puts "What a lovely name!" if name == 'Chris' 
puts "Wow! That\'s an even better name than Chris" if name == 'Joey' 
gets
```

Comment: Just curious. Isn't this line 'puts "Hello, " + name + "."' should be in new line?

Answer (score 0):

The code is missing `end`. `test expression` and `body` should be separated unless you use `then` or `:`.

```
puts "Hello, what\'s your name?"
name = gets.chomp
puts "Hello, " + name + "." # This line should be separated from previous line.

if name == 'Chris'
  puts "What a lovely name!"
end # <----
if name == 'Joey'
  puts "Wow! That\'s an even better name than Chris"
end # <---
gets
```

---

Answer (score 0):

if (*pun intended*) you want to write these on one line

```
if name == 'Chris' puts "What a lovely name!"
if name == 'Joey' puts "Wow! That\'s an even better name than Chris"
```

do it like this

```
puts "What a lovely name!" if name == 'Chris'
puts "Wow! That\'s an even better name than Chris" if name == 'Joey'
```

Comment: And for your second line inside of double quotes, you do not need to escape the single quote/apostrophe.  Style wise, perhaps use single quotes unless you need double quotes for interpolation or perhaps to not need to escape single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to escape single quotes when that single quote is not used as a string delimiter.

You can also use an if/else statement.

```
puts "Hello, what's your name?"
name = gets.chomp
puts 'Hello, ' + name + '.'

if name == 'Chris'
  puts 'What a lovely name!'
else name == 'Joey'
  puts "Wow! That's an even better name than Chris"
end
gets
```

More inline with what your code is suggesting, perhaps:

```
puts "Hello, what's your name?"
name = gets.chomp
puts 'Hello, ' + name + '.'

puts 'What a lovely name!' if name == 'Chris'
puts "Wow! That's an even better name than Chris" if name == 'Joey'
gets
```

Again, notice I only used double quotes where I would need to escape the apostrophe.

Note that double quoted strings allow "string interpolation" also called "Variable interpolation", if you want to search for that, but are not necessary to use them in general.  Style may dictate otherwise, perhaps.